# Variables retain their value in a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

If I run this simple code in a console app:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    Dim s As String = i.ToString()
    Dim x As Decimal
    If i = 1 Then
        x = Decimal.Parse(s)
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())
Next
Console.ReadLine()
```

Unexpectedly, `x` retains its value of 1 and so 1 gets printed 10 times. I thought each iteration of the loop was its own code block, and that the state didn't carry over? Why does this happen? I would expect `x` to have the default value of `System.Decimal`.

Same thing happens in C#, except that the complier won't let you call `ToString()` on an uninitialized variable, but if you set a breakpoint in Visual Studio, you can see that `x` retains its value of 1.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string s = i.ToString();
    Decimal x;
    if(i == 1)
    {
        x = Decimal.Parse(s);
    }
    // Value of x remains 1
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You don't need `ToString`, just use `Console.WriteLine(x)`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope

Comment: If you want to initialise `x` on each iteration, use `Dim x As Decimal = 0`.

Comment: For C#, in the loop, when i equals 2 through 10, x has not been assigned a value. If you are able to compile and run the program, the value of x can not be relied on. When I try to compile this with a line that tries to print out x where your comment is, then I get a compile error that states the value of x is unassigned.

Comment: Works as expected -> you only change x value when i = 1 so.... Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding VB.NET take a look about scope [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope). In the "**Block Scope**" section there is a note which states the following:

> Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its lifetime is
> still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block more than
> once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous
> value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise to
> initialize block variables at the beginning of the block.

So this behavior is by design and you should initialize the variable to whatever value your code needs.

I modified your code to show that the first time x is initialized to 0 but after that it retains the value of 1.

```
    For i As Integer = 1 To 10
        Dim s As String = i.ToString()
        Dim x As Decimal
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())
        If i = 1 Then
            x = Decimal.Parse(s)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

> thought each iteration of the loop was its own code block, and that the state didn't carry over

It does "carry over."

`int i` is scoped to the entire range of the loop, with values from 1 to 10.

The `if` statement only executes on the first iteration, and `x` is scoped as a local variable to the *outer method* (assuming the loop is entered), not only the loop body. That being said, after & outside the loop, `x == 1` as well.

In fact, `Decimal x;` in the loop is redundant, and you have the same execution logic as

```
string s;
Decimal x;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    s = i.ToString();

    if(i == 1)
    {
        x = Decimal.Parse(s);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
// x still defined here
```

Comment: The code you showed *isn't* the same as scoping the variable inside the loop though.  When the variable is scoped within the loop the code *doesn't compile*, so your assertion that it behaves the same is just false.  The code doesn't compile precisely because variables *are* scoped to the block that they're in, not the whole method.

Comment: Yeah but if I try to access `x` outside the loop in my original code it gives a compilation error "variable is not declared". If I try to access a variable declared within the loop in the loop definition, it also doesn't allow it. So it just doesn't make sense that the value remains...

Comment: Ah, here it is from MS: "Even if the scope of a variable is limited to a block, its lifetime is still that of the entire procedure. If you enter the block more than once during the procedure, each block variable retains its previous value. To avoid unexpected results in such a case, it is wise to initialize block variables at the beginning of the block." Still seems stupid to me, but it is what it is...

Comment: @OneCricketeer seems to be right. I have tested the VB and C# snippets with some extra behaviour to see what happens, and Dim x As Decimal does indeed behave as if declared outside the loop, though it's declared inside. To a C# developer like me, that's silly, but it is what it is. Whether this is according to language spec I don't know.

Comment: "It is what it is", haha. Two minds, one thought.

Comment: @Servy The variable `x` isn't scoped to the loop, though, so not sure I understand your point (admittedly, I didn't try to compile anything here)

Comment: @John: You should provide what you found as the answer to your own question - it's an interesting VB quirk that often catches developers by surprise.

Comment: @OneCricketeer It is in the question, and this answer says the two are identical.  But they don't behave identically, contrary to the what the answer says.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas It's not just VB.NET. It's C# as well. It's just that the compiler won't let you `console.writeline` for the uninitialized variable. But if you follow it through in the debugger, the value is retained.

Comment: @John: Yes, but since C# doesn't let you actually do anything with the variable when it's uninitialized, it's effectively not a 'feature' of C#.

Answer (score 0):

To make some sense of what you want, it should be just like this:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    If i = 1 Then
      Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Parse(i.ToString()))
    End If
Next
```

This will give you the same result you want but it is readable.